# Storing value of tracking column in DB instead of a config file in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have tracking column in my logstash config file as follows:

```
tracking_column => "updated_ts"
tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
last_run_metadata_path => "/elastic/.customer"
```

The tracking date is stored in the .customer file.

How can I store the tracking column in DB rather that in .customer file?
I have googled but realised that no one is doing that. Hope anyone can help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible, the `last_run_metadata_path` needs to [point to a file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-last_run_metadata_path).